# React-native throwing unexpected token error on import statement

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

React-native is throwing an unexpected token in a firebase import statement. I have been trying to fix this for a long time. I have already installed @react-native-firebase/auth with `npm i install @react-native-firebase/auth`. Please help.
This is the error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please include the error as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably happening because you cannot import as you did in your code.

As the documentation states for [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

> The export parameters specify individual named exports, while the `import * as name` syntax imports all of them. Below are examples to clarify the syntax.

You need to put there an alias, if you need all of the exported objects from a library as the following:

```
import * as auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
```

I hope that helps!